# Problemas al Filtrar fechas con stored procedure

Tags: mysql-workbench

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `bsp_VER_FECHAS`(pFecha_Inicio date,pFecha_Fin date)
SALIR:BEGIN

IF (SELECT Fecha_Inicio  FROM ejemplo.turnos WHERE
((Fecha_Inicio between pFecha_Inicio AND pFecha_Fin and Fecha_Fin >= pFecha_Fin ) OR (Fecha_Inicio <= pFecha_Inicio AND Fecha_Fin BETWEEN pFecha_Inicio AND pFecha_Fin) OR (Fecha_Inicio BETWEEN pFecha_Inicio AND pFecha_Fin AND Fecha_Fin BETWEEN pFecha_Inicio AND pFecha_Fin) OR (Fecha_Inicio <= pFecha_Fin AND Fecha_Fin >= pFecha_Inicio))) THEN

SELECT 'FECHA OCUPADA ' AS Mensaje;
LEAVE SALIR;
END IF;

START TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO ejemplo.turnos VALUES(0,pId_Paciente, pFecha_Inicio,pFecha_Fin);
   SET pId_Turno = LAST_INSERT_ID();
     SELECT CONCAT('OK', pId_Turno) AS Mensaje;
  COMMIT;   
END
```

Buenas noches con este stored procedure pude filtrar fechas para evitar solapamiento de fechas,el problema es cuando ingreso fechas como en el ejemplo siguiente:

```
CALL bsp_VER_FECHAS ('2019-02-20','2019-02-07');
```

el cual no me deberia dejar insertar.Me gustaria filtra este tipo de fechas y evitar insertar fechas antiguas ya que debo asignar turnos presentes y futuros ,si alguien me podria ayudar.Muchas Gracias

Comment: ¿Por qué no lo intentas mejor con un `TRIGGER` del tipo `BEFORE INSERT`? Lo que haría sería impedir cualquier `INSERT` de una fecha pasada en la tabla. Aunque en el contexto de una aplicación esto debería bloquearse también a otro nivel, por ejemplo, si hay un botón para lanzar la inserción, mantenerlo desactivado si se verifica que no se dan las condiciones requeridas para insertar.

Answer (score 0):

```
   Buenas tardes pude solucionar el problema con el siguiente codigo :

IF not pFecha_Inicio  >= current_date() THEN      --  --
    SELECT 'LA FECHA INICIO NO PUEDE SER INGRESADA' AS Mensaje;
    LEAVE SALIR;
END IF; 

IF not pFecha_fin  >= pFecha_Inicio  THEN          --  --
    SELECT 'LA FECHA FIN NO PUEDE SER INGRESADA' AS Mensaje;
    LEAVE SALIR;
END IF;
```

Espero le sirva gracias por responder